# How to properly type a DynamoDBDocumentClient?

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

When creating a new DynamoDBDocumentClient I'm getting this Typecsript error: `Unsafe assignment of an any value`

How to properly type DynamoDBDocumentClient ?

```
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb"
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb"

const client = new DynamoDBClient({})
const ddbDocClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client) //Unsafe assignment of an `any` value
```

Here's my `.eslintrc` config:

```
//...
overrides: [
    {
      extends: [
        // "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",//<-- Does not show the mentioned error
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
      ],
      files: ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      parserOptions: {
        project: "tsconfig.json",
      },
    },
  ]
//...
```

Comment: Sorry @Windcheck, unfortunately not able to reproduce, this has always worked for me. Perhaps sharing the ts-config, TS version, and package.json may help to investigate further?

Comment: @Conor Added the plugin config. See if you can reproduce it now.

Comment: This sounds eerily similar to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76467691/typescript-eslint-warning-on-one-aws-client-constructor-dynamodb-but-not-anot