# typescript eslint warning on one aws client constructor (dynamodb), but not another (s3)

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, typescript-eslint

I'm pretty new to Typescript, so maybe I'm overlooking something obvious, but I'm unable to use the AWS v3 Javascript SDK without triggering what appear to be totally bogus @typescript-eslint warnings.  Here's a trivial snippet that reproduces one inconsistency:

```
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
new S3Client({});
new DynamoDBClient({});
```

The S3 client construction is fine.  No warnings.
However, the last line with the DynamoDB client construction yields `ESLint: Unsafe construction of an any type value.(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call)`

This is basically straight out of their "hello dynamodb" docs.

Both packages are installed, and the types look basically the same, though there could be some subtlety buried in the details of the configuration types, I guess (slightly simplified for clarity):

```
export declare class S3Client extends __Client<__HttpHandlerOptions, ServiceInputTypes, ServiceOutputTypes, S3ClientResolvedConfig> {
    readonly config: S3ClientResolvedConfig;
    constructor(configuration: S3ClientConfig);
}
```

vs

```
export declare class DynamoDBClient extends __Client<__HttpHandlerOptions, ServiceInputTypes, ServiceOutputTypes, DynamoDBClientResolvedConfig> {
    readonly config: DynamoDBClientResolvedConfig;
    constructor(configuration: DynamoDBClientConfig);
}
```

They look basically the same.  How can a constructor be considered to return an `any`?  That's so weird.

My `package.json` contains:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.351.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.282.0",
...
```

Comment: I too have this issue, and have yet to find a cause. However, if you want to suppress the ESLint complaint, you can add "// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies" before your DynamoDB imports. At first I suspected this was due to version mismatches, however, even with the same version the problem persists.

Comment: Ok, that was flaky.  I blew away node-modules and package-lock.json, did a full new npm install.  Didn't fix it... directly.  But then, I added a syntax error to the file (got an error), then fixed the syntax error.  Somewhere in that process, something got cleaned up and the error on `new DynamoDBClient({})` went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a build/tooling caching problem.  If I run eslint from the command line, I don't get any errors, but inside WebStorm 2022.3.2, the eslint warning persists on the every `new DynamoDBClient()` even if I completely clear the line and retype it, add a second copy, change the parameters, paste the code into a new file in the same project, etc.

I was able to clear the spurious warning by doing a `File > Invalidate Caches... > Just Restart`.  Perhaps a regular restart would have also been enough.

The repro (for WebStorm) seems to be to reference the class with eslint tooling enabled before doing a `npm install` of the associated package.  The error is then sticky **even after installing the package**.  Not sure if this is a general problem with eslint-before-definition (I'd assume lots of people would hit that!) or if there's something about the complexity of the AWS code that triggers the issue.

Leaving this question up just in case anyone else using WebStorm bumps into the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this issue using the following latest versions of both packages:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.352.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.352.0",
    "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb": "^3.272.0"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

Are you able to provide reproducible code which I can investigate?

Comment: Thanks for checking... I'm able to repro, but only inside WebStorm.  If I paste in any AWS client construction code (just tried SQS as an example) and it gets linted before I do a npm install, the error is sticky even after I do the install.